# How can I return a value from an asynchronous method without stopping the method in .Net (c#)?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

Consider the following example:

```
public Fruit ProcessFruitBasket(List<Fruit> fruits) {
    Fruit result = null;
    foreach (var fruit in fruits) {
        ProcessFruit(fruit);
        if (fruit.MeetsSomeCondition()) result = fruit;
    }
    return fruit;
}
```

The method ProcessFruitBasket() needs to do something (ProcessFruit()) to every item in the list. Additionally, it needs to find one particular item that meets some condition and return it.
The current version is single-threaded, and as a result, the caller will need to wait until all of the items are processed before it can get back its result, even if the one it wants is the first item in the list.

What I would like to do is run ProcessFruitBasket() asynchronously, and have it return the desired value when it finds it so the caller can continue on with the result. However, the ProcessFruitBasket() should still continue to process the rest of the list.

Alternatively, if I could somehow start a Task and have it fill a variable the caller has a reference to, the maybe there is a way that the caller can await the variable being populated (not null anymore?) but not await the whole task?

I have some ideas of how the .Net Tasks namespace might potentially have solved this, but I haven't been able to find any relevant examples. It's possible this isn't an option? I have a clunky solution in mind where the code could loop through the list until it found the right item, and then fire off a task that continues to process the rest of the list asynchronously while the original method returns the found result. It seems like there could be a cleaner mechanism already in place for this. Possibly a way of using Parallel.ForEach() that I haven't found yet?

The important part is that the caller should await the *result* without having to await the processing of the *entire list*.

Comment: You can hook up tasks together to do this, manually, `async/await` won't help you here. What you can do is return a `Task<Fruit>`, that you get from `TaskCompletionSource<Fruit>`, and then call `.TrySetResult` on this source when you have the value. You will need to manually combine tasks with `.ContinueWith` and so on to string them together though.

Comment: Also have a look at [C# Feature request: Async stream generators](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8).

Comment: Maybe too simple but I would just raise an event and pass the result as an Argument, or the already mentioned callback.

Comment: depends if its windows app or web app. You dont want to raise events in web app

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Or, rather than wiring it all up by hand using continuations and completion sources, you could just use `await` and make the code much simpler and more effective.

Comment: It's never a good idea to have some running code without a "handle" to it. A `Task` is a good kind of handle for code; it at least allows other code to detect any errors that the code would run into. I would take a step back and question the design first. If your code *really* needs to return *and* keep running, then I'd recommend returning both a `Fruit` and a `Task` (e.g., in a tuple).

Comment: if you know it is error prone and-or only logging purposes its perfectly legal but gc will destroy any thread if there is no handle to it

Comment: @TakeMeAsAGuest That's just not true.  The GC doesn't manage threads at all, it manages objects in memory, and a thread itself is *inherently* a root.  You can most certainly fire off a thread and have it do something without holding onto any handles, and the thread still cannot be destroyed.

Comment: no gc threats Thread's like all objects and Thread's destructor destroys cpu thread as well. you can test it yourself. in a windows form application spawn a thread in button handler. if there is no root after event handler run it will eventually be destoyed

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function

```
public void ProcessFruitBasket(List<Fruit> fruits, Func<Fruit> callback) {
    foreach (var fruit in fruits) {
        ProcessFruit(fruit);
        if (fruit.MeetsSomeCondition()) 
            callback(fruit);
    }
}
```

also on side note that if you dont `await` asynchronous method then .net will execute next statements until you call `await` on asynchronous method.

**Update 1**

```
    public async Task ProcessFruitBasket(IList<Fruit> fruits, Action<Fruit> callBack)
    {
        foreach (var fruit in fruits)
        {
            var process = ProcessFruit(fruit); // DO NOT await here

            // do something else here

            await process; // you have to await here since you have to check condition on processed fruit
            if (fruit.MeetsSomeCondition())
            {
                callBack(fruit);
            }
        }
    }
    public async Task ProcessFruit(Fruit fruit)
    {
        // do async actions here
        await Task.FromResult<int>(0);
    }

    public void Callback(Fruit fruit)
    {
        // Do something with the fruit
    }
```

Comment: function => *delegate*

Comment: I thought about this possibility, but the problem is that once the loop hits the callback and calls it, then that blocks the loop from continuing until the callback returns. Also, how does the initial calling process know that the callback has been called, so that it can continue its processing, but not await the whole loop? The whole point is to return back to the caller of this loop so that caller can continue on while this loop finishes out. There may be some way that this could be made to work, but it feels a little like my idea of firing off something to continue the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work. You will want to get back something representing the remaining processing so that you can await it at some point. I would use an object to capture both things:

```
public class FruitProcessingResult
{
    public bool FruitWasFound { get; set; }
    public Fruit FruitMeetingCondition { get; set; }
    public Task RemainingProcessing { get; set; }
}

    private async Task<FruitProcessingResult> ProcessFruitBasket(List<Fruit> fruits)
    {
        var result = new FruitProcessingResult();

        //Kick off all fruit processing
        var tasks = fruits.Select(f => ProcessAndTestFruit(f, result)).ToList();

        while (tasks.Any())
        {
            var completed = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
            tasks.Remove(completed);

            lock (result)
            {
                if (result.FruitWasFound)
                {
                    result.RemainingProcessing = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }

        result.RemainingProcessing = Task.CompletedTask;
        return result;
    }

    private async Task ProcessAndTestFruit(Fruit fruit, FruitProcessingResult result)
    {          
        //Process each individual fruit async if you can, otherwise kick off a task
        await ProcessFruitAsync(fruit);
        //await Task.Run(() => ProcessFruitAsync(fruit));

        if (fruit.MeetsSomeCondition())
        {
            lock (result)
            {
                if (!result.FruitWasFound)
                {
                    result.FruitWasFound = true;
                    result.FruitMeetingCondition = fruit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```